# Best way to make an HTTP Post with json body in angular 9

Tags: angular, http, post, service, angular9

Hi there i am working on a project where i need to save 3 text box fields.
I am having a hard time finding out how to post with a json body. This is what I have so far.
I keep finding bits and pieces online and I am so confused.

```
  onClickMe() {
    this.dataService.saveOrder(this.order);
  }

saveOrder (order: order): Observable<order> {
    const href = 'http://localhost:7000/api/SaveOrder';
    const config = { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json') }
    return this.httpClient.post<order>(href, order, config)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError('updateOrder', order))
      );
  }

export interface Order {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  status: string;
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason your setting a config, or is just something you've grabbed from an example?

Comment: lol it is something i just saw in an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm going to assume that you don't really need the headers to be set, and omit them in this example, there are use cases when you would but honestly I'd say in a majority of cases they can be left out.

First I'd name your functions a little more appropriately onClickMe is very obscure in what it actually does, this is both for your benefit and someone else when reading your code, you'll be amazed how much it helps when you come back to some old code you've not read for months!

**Component**

```
saveOrderToDB(newOrder: Order): void{
  this.orderService.saveNewOrder(newOrder).subscribe((response) => {
    console.log('Succesfully posted', newOrder)
    // Or you can log the response, response.message ect depending on what the backend returns
    console.log(response);
  })
}
```

**Service**

```
url = 'http://localhost:7000/api/' // Use this as your base url across all http methods within your service and append the extra parts such as the SaveOrder within the methods themselves

saveOrder(order: Order): Observable < Order > {
  return this.http.post<Order>(`${this.url}SaveOrder`, order)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('updateOrder', order))
    )
}
```

Also the Angular documentation is honestly a great port of call for getting to grips with the http service - https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: Thank you so much. How do i get the order id, name, and status from the textbox into the saveOrderToDB? Because in my orginal post onClickMe just goes and get the order object. I am unaware how to pass it thru the button.

Comment: Also i keep getting this error 465789:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:7071/api/SaveOrder' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Comment: Right the CORS issues watch this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ka8vG5miErk&t=913s

Comment: With regards to the id, & name I'm assuming your using Angular forms to submit this data correct?